# vue-codemirror4 with bvModal requires click to display code

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, codemirror

I'm making small app on vue2.7 where there is modal (bvModal) when a row is clicked on ItemDetails component. The popup modal shows the codeblock using v-model.

The problem is when the modal is visible, it is empty initally without any code. Once I click anywhere in the modal display area, the codeblock is visible.

I have provided the [codesandox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/codemirror-bvmodal-gq9k8z?file=/src/components/ItemDetails.vue)
I'm using vue-codemirror v4 & bootstrap-vue v2.23.

Here is screenshot of the modal before and after clicks:
Before Click
[image: before click]

After Click
[image: after click]